# appending a file extension in a C++ progam

Tags: c++, append

I am writing a C++ program, using the ifstream ofstream functions. I ask the user which file to open, and then ask them what to name the file. Please look at the code below and help me figure out how to use the append function properly.

```
cout << "Please type the new name for your file ( File must end in '.txt'): ";
cin>>outf; // stores name of requested txt file
if (!outf.rfind(".txt"))
{
 outf.append(".txt");
}
```

could use suggestions....

Answer (score 2):

First you need a function to ask if the string ends with ".txt".  `outf.rfind(".txt")` will find the string ".txt" *anywhere* in the string.  (`rfind()` differs from `find()` in that it starts searching from the end, but it can find a match anywhere in the string.)

```
bool ends_with(std::string const & str, std::string const & suffix)
{
    // If the string is smaller than the suffix then there is no match.
    if (str.size() < suffix.size()) { return false; }

    return 0 == str.compare(str.size() - suffix.size(),
                            suffix.size(),
                            suffix,
                            0,
                            suffix.size());
}
```

Now we can just use `std::string`'s `+=` operator overload to append to the string if this function returns false:

```
if (!ends_with(outf, ".txt")) {
    outf += ".txt";
}
```

([See a live demo](http://ideone.com/SYKU0C).)

Comment: I appreciate the help. looking at your profile I can see you have a whole world of knowledge, so you helping me is greatly appreciated. Because I am somewhat new to C++ programming I couldn't totally understand all of what you put here...but your answer did put me in the right direction and was less complex. Please see my answer

Comment: @Jeremy Unfortunately your approach is still incorrect.  If you need help understanding my answer, just ask here.  We can move to SO chat and I would be happy to clarify anything.

Answer (score 0):

the Previous answer set me in the right direction, and this worked for what I was looking for...hopefully this helps someone else looking for the same thing.

```
cout << "Please type the new name for your file ( File must end in '.XML'): ";
cin>>outf; // stores name of requested xml file

string y=".xml";
if (outf.rfind(".xml")!= true)
{
    outf.append(y);
}
```

Comment: Now try this with `outf = "a.txt.zip";`.  You won't append `.txt` because the name contains `.txt` -- but it is not at the end!  This is why you need the `ends_with()` function in my answer.

Comment: I actually found out the flaw this morning...when I accidentally added the wrong extension to the file. I revisited your answer, then noticed the live demo you added.....Again thank you, and thanks for the patience...